Concurrency of lines connecting incenters and vertices in the degenerate tetrahedron
This problem appeared on USA MOP 2024. Let $ABCD$ be a quadrilateral and $I_A, I_B, I_C, I_D$ be the incenters of $BCD, CDA,
DAB, ABC$ respectively. Show that if three of the lines $AI_A, BI_B, CI_C, DI_D$ are
concurrent, then all four are concurrent.
So far, there is a similar problem when $ABCD$ is a tetrahedron. It can be found here (Solve a tetrahedron with given lengths of three edges and a certain property).
I have checked the scenario for 2D $ABCD$, and the condition $AB \cdot CD = AC \cdot BD = AD \cdot BC$ does not necessarily hold. I have also tried to backtrack and find the equivalent condition for $ABCD$ and $I_AI_BI_CI_D$ being perspective; however, to no avail. Any solutions, hints, or suggestions are welcome.
